# How to eliminate characters in excess in a string

Tags: r, cmd

I have piece of R code that sends notifications to Teams based on the content of a table:

```
    # Loop through each message and send Teams notification
for (i in seq_along(messages)) {
  message <- messages[[i]]
  payload <- list(text = message)
  json_payload <- gsub("\"", "\\\"", jsonlite::toJSON(payload))  # escape double quotes with a single backslash
  command <- sprintf('curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "%s" %s', json_payload, teams_webhook_url)  # use single quotes for the command string and double quotes for the header value
  system(command, intern = TRUE)  # use intern = TRUE to capture the output of the system command
  print(command)
}
```

This code throws an error because the format of the string is not correct. If I print command this is the output:

[1] "curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{"text":["Subnet 10.0.0.0 has a higher than usual round trip time:  0.07 ms"]}" [https://my.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/webhook"](https://my.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/webhook%22)

The correct output should be as follows:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"text\": \"Subnet 100.95.13.0 has a higher than usual round trip time:  0.25 ms\"}" https://my.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/webhook"
```

I need to eliminate:

- The initial "
- The \ in front of "Content-Type:
- The \ after json
- The \ before "{"text":
- The two [ ]
- The \ after ms"}

I'm having a hard time understanding how to eliminate these characters in those specific positions... All the attempts I made leave the string unchanged.  See below some of the attempts:

```
json_payload <- gsub("\"", "\\\\\\\\\"", jsonlite::toJSON(payload))


for (i in seq_along(messages)) {
  message <- messages[[i]]
  payload <- list(text = message)
  json_payload <- gsub("\"", "\\\\\\\"", jsonlite::toJSON(payload))  # escape double quotes with three backslashes
  command <- sprintf("curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '%s' %s", json_payload, teams_webhook_url)
  output <- system(command, intern = TRUE)
  output <- gsub("^\"", "", output) # remove the first "
  cat(output, "\n")
}


for (i in seq_along(messages)) {
  message <- messages[[i]]
  payload <- list(text = message)
  json_payload <- jsonlite::toJSON(payload, auto_unbox = TRUE, escape_unicode = FALSE)
  command <- sprintf('curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d \'%s\' %s', json_payload, teams_webhook_url)
  system(command, intern = TRUE)
}

for (i in seq_along(messages)) {
  message <- messages[[i]]
  payload <- list(text = message)
  json_payload <- gsub('"', '\\\\"', jsonlite::toJSON(payload))
  command <- sprintf("curl -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -d '%s' %s", json_payload, teams_webhook_url)
  command <- gsub("\\[|\\]", "", command)
  command <- gsub("\\\\", "", command)
  system(command, intern = TRUE)
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `system2` (which is just as broken as `system`), I suggest `processx::run`. If you look at `system2`, it simply `paste`s arguments together, only shell-quoting the command itself. Both are fundamentally broken and unsafe to use in any other than most trivial of supervised settings.

Comment: I changed the script: command <- c("curl", "-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "-d", json_payload, teams_webhook_url)
    command_str <- paste0(command, collapse = " ") # convert command to a string
    result <- processx::run(command_str) but even passing a hardcoded string as the command, I get "Error in `process_initialize(self, private, command, args, stdin, stdout, …`:
! Native call to `processx_exec` failed
Caused by error in `chain_call(c_processx_exec, command, c(command, args), pty, pty_options, …` . what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to read the documentation for [`processx::run`](https://processx.r-lib.org/reference/run.html), namely that its first two arguments are `command=` (character vector length 1, _the command_) and `args=` (a vector of arguments). Don't collapse your `command_str`, just use `processx::run(command[1], command[-1])`.

Comment: I was trying to pass along a single string, but in the end I made it work by manually adding the prefixes and suffixes to the payload. I'm posting below the version of the code that works (it's not elegant, but it does the job...)

Answer (score 0):

This is the version that works:

```
# Loop through each message and send Teams notification
if (exists("messages")) {
  for (i in seq_along(messages)) {
    message <- messages[[i]]
    payload_1 <- paste0('{\"text\": \"', message, "\\", '"}"')
    payload_2 <- capture.output(cat(payload_1))
    payload_3 <- gsub("\\\\", "\\", payload_2)
    payload <- substr(payload_3, 1, nchar(payload_3) -1)
    command <- "curl"
    arguments <-  c("-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "-d", payload, teams_webhook_url)
    result <- processx::run(
                            command = command,
                            args = arguments, 
                            error_on_status = TRUE, 
                            echo_cmd = TRUE
                            )
  }
} else {
  cat("Error: 'messages' variable not defined.\n")
}
```

Comment: What is `capture.output(cat(payload_1))` supposed to be doing? I can't imagine a situation where it isn't effectively a no-op. Further, your `gsub` for backslashes does not seem necessary unless you are intentionally adding double-backslashes somewhere for a known reason. Either way, glad you were able to figure out `processx::run` and get something working!